# Is it possible to show answer based on results in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I want to make a troubleshooting tool where the customer could answer the questions and in the end get the suggestion on how the problem could be solved. The questions are dependent. So if you choose option A you go to the question C and if you choose option B you will see question D and so on. And in the end based on the answers we could get the solution proposal.

For example, if AC is chosen = "reinstall software", if BD is chosen = "restart pc". It is just examples but it is the functionality I would like to obtain. It does not have to be Google Forms, other free solutions are also welcome. Google Forms is just the first I came up with. I have tried making dependent questions and it worked, so it is the suggestion/answer I am most concerned about.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

They say a picture is a thousand words.

In this case a form is. So I prepared a form that may help you. Please have a look.

> http://goo.gl/forms/vMPnaqVkEi

Please keep in mind that it is a general guideline. You can always enrich the form with more questions, confirmation emails, follow ups, support ticket numbers etc.

---

The provided example (link to the form) takes advantage of the "*Go to section based on answer*" advanced feature of the forms by creating simple loops through multiple choice questions directing the user to specific choices/sections; thus creating a predetermined route. Questions are all required as well.

Please have a look at the following explanatory images to further comprehend the form mapping:

1. ...

[image: image01]

2. ...

[image: image02]

3. ...

[image: image03]

4. ...

[image: image04]

5. ...

[image: image05]

6. ...

[image: image06]

We close each loop by directing the user to our final step/section (Tech Support) that allows submission of the form.